# How do the Guard, sticky, and round bits work and affect floating point Representation?

Tags: floating-point

I've got a test on this tomorrow, my instructor's lectures aren't up, and the notes are ambiguous...

Anyhow, we've been covering floating point operations, specifically addition, and he mentioned these three bits. While I can surmise their meaning to a degree, I'm wondering if anyone could explain concretely what they are and perhaps provide some examples showing how they work?

If it would be useful, the language I'm learning this in is MIPS, which does Round-to-Even.

Comment: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/flpt.apprec.html

Comment: Should've scrolled further, sorry. Quick summary: Lowest bit of mantissa is set to one if addition of all 3 of these bits would carry.